# Dynamically generated routes/URLs from Model fields in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Describing the following scenario:

1. A user signs up and provides a firstName (john) and a lastName (jagger)
2. A route is automatically generated for the default domain i.e. www.asdasd.com/john.doe
3. A guest visits www.asdasd.com/john.doe and is taken to the 'view' action of the controller for this user

Is something like this possible? I do not know how to form something like this in routes.rb

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It doesnt generate routes dynamically but instead it lets u use the name as the ID.

Comment: Well, creating a route what would use /id instead /users/id is pretty simple imo.. something like: match "/:id" => "users#view"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Wasn't sure if this gem masks the route or literally uses a different ID. Should've looked at it clearer. It would probably #show if using standard scaffolding.

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides method in your models called **to_param**. This method returns URL for your model instance.
 For example: you have model **User**
 user = User.find_by_name('John')
user_path(user) # => /users/1

You can ovverride to_param method to return URL such as:
**/users/John**

Here you can read more:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param